# Efficiency - Replacing word in middle of sentence

Tags: java, string, search, performance

My problem is that I have a big String and I want to change all the "i " into "I ". However I cannot do this efficiently enough. I know there are previous questions asked on replacing parts of a String, but I am unsure what is the fastest method.

Some kind I have tried:

a)

```
if (question.charAt(i)=='i' && question.charAt(i+1)==' ')
{
   question = question.substring(0,i) + 'I' + question.substring(i+1);
}
```

---

b) (100-200x slower than attempt a)

```
question = question.replace("i ", "I ");
```

---

c) (About 100x slower than atempt a)

```
question = question.replaceAll("i ", "I ");
```

I have never done much efficient programming and neither of these cuts it for how efficient I need this to be. Is there a faster way that I don't know about?

Comment: In general, for a String of moderate length, the cost of scanning, using whatever mechanism, will be swamped by the cost (both measured and, more importantly, "hidden" in the GC cycle) of breaking up and reconstituting the String object.

Comment: And note that your examples above is comparing apples to oranges since the first case does not scan to find the location to replace.

Comment: I hope you're taking care to warm up the JVM and take the average over a large number of runs when microbenchmarking like this. Microbenchmarks are notoriously hard to get right.

Answer (score 1):

A solution that should be a bit more efficient than yours (which is already really efficient) is the following.

```
public String convertWord(String word)
{
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

    char[] charArr = word.toCharArray();

    for(int i = 0; i < charArr.length; i++)
    {
        // Single character case
        if(charArr[i] == 'i' && (i+1 < charArr.length)  && charArr[i+1] = ' ')
        {
            sb.append('I');
        }
        else
        {   
            sb.append(word.charAt(i));
        }
    }

    return sb.toString();
}
```

Comment: After re-read of answer: `i++` when matching since you definitively know the next char is `' '`